# Unable to set cookie on Safari (Works on Chrome)

Tags: cookies, safari, dns, cross-domain

Hi I have been creating my first MERN stack web application and deployed frontend and backend on separate domains. 

Frontend (netlify) : example.netlify.app 
Backend (heroku) : example.herokuapp.com 
Github (this is my repository, just in case) : https://github.com/dbwjd5864/YumPlan 

So getting cookies from Backend and storing in order to request another api calls with cookies worked fine with Chrome (I haven't tried yet with Firefox but I believe it works as well) 

However, when I tested it with Safari, I can see cookies on [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcti1.png) but it was not stored for later request, so I couldn't get authorized. However, when I uncheck **[Prevent cross-site tracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqvzf.png)** under Safari preferences, I could get cookies for the later API calls.

I guess this is a **cors** issue which came from Safari property. I spent so much time to find a way to solve it but I couldn't. Is there any way to make it possible for Safari users to get login and set token on different domains?

Or Should I just use the same domain, for example, I deploy the frontend and backend on Heroku together to use the same domain? 
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?